# Create a file and save it to another server

Tags: php, ftp

I create a json file and save it in my server where my script save.

```
<?
$format='epub_text';
$ver='1.0.0';

$posts = array('content_id'=> $dir,'content_version'=> $ver,'content_name'=> $title, 'content_format'=> $format);

$response = $posts;
$nama_file= $dir.'.json';
$fp = fopen($nama_file, 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
fclose($fp);
?>
```

After save it I need to copy the file result to another server, a ftp server . Any advice how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

To use FTP in PHP, you can use cURL. Here's a [tutorial](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/ftpupload.html) straight from the developers of the library :)

Comment: Thanks for the information @David, I've seen the tutorial and try but it doesn't work. No error message. is $localfile means the file on my computer, not on my server? I give $localfile = "http://mydomain/path/myFile" and it doesn't work.

Comment: localfile would be the path to the file on the filesystem.